# Mysql select not in query

Tags: php, sql

```
SELECT t.* from test t where t.name ='test123' and t.subject NOT IN (SELECT * from result_master where email = 'fusion1234@gmail.com')
```

The above query gives the following error:

> 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) error display

Any idea what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

The error says it all.

When you use `IN`, you should select only the required column in subquery (do not use `*`):

```
SELECT t.* 
from test t 
where t.name ='test123' 
  and t.subject NOT IN (SELECT subject 
                        from result_master 
                        where email = 'fusion1234@gmail.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner query should be

```
               (SELECT subject 
                from result_master 
                where email = 'YourEmail@domain.com')
```

**Why ?**

Because , in your question you were comparing email column value with **Multiple** column values.

Means in subquery you were returning say 10 fields , but you can use one column only. Its actually comma separated list internally but you were giving wrong result for outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Although the simple solution is to use `NOT IN`, of ten `NOT EXISTS` is more appropriate for this sort of query.  You can use `*` with `NOT EXISTS`, but I prefer to use `1`:

```
SELECT t.*
from test t
where t.name ='test123' and
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  from result_master rm
                  where rm.email = 'fusion1234@gmail.com' and 
                        t.subject = rm.subject
                 );
```

Why is this better?  There is a semantic difference between the two versions.  If any value of `result_master.subject` is `NULL` in the subquery, then `NOT IN` will never return any rows.  `NOT EXISTS` does what is normally wanted in this situation -- it ignores the `NULL` values.

Note:  even when the column (say `subject`) is declared to be `NOT NULL`, then I am still biased toward `NOT EXISTS`.  It also often has better performance characteristics than `NOT IN`.